# Image does not fit properly in collectionCell

Tags: swift, image, layout, uicollectionview

In Swift 3. My app has a table view and a detail view with is a view controller. Here I added a  collection view. An array of images must be presented. The images adapt themselves beautifully if in portrait I check the content mode in scaler to fill. In ladscape it works in aspectFill. Vice-versa, the layout does not fit. I did the following
 in cellForItem At:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = myCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellCollection", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.cellImage.image = UIImage(named: array[indexPath.item])

    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape{
        cell.cellImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    }
    else if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait{
        cell.cellImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    }

    return cell
}
```

It does not work. May be I have some inconsistencies  from portrait to landscape.
I would appreciate your help. If you want to take a look at the project in git:
[https://github.com/ricardovaldes/tareaFinalHoteles.git[1](https://github.com/ricardovaldes/tareaFinalHoteles.git). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your issue is unclear. And why would you want a different content mode depending on the device's orientation?

Comment: Just because the image fits properly and the scroll of the collection view behaves properly as well. I do not know why at the moment, but very well in scale to fill when in portrait and aspect fill when in landscape. Just take a look at the project in GitHub. thanks.

Comment: You need to explain what issue you are having. It's not clear. No one should have to build and run your project just to know what problem you are having. That's not how this site works.

Comment: OK maddy. I want to make my images to display in the scroll of my collection. In portrait it looks very well when content mode is in scale to fill. I use size for item at to try  to configure my cell.

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let size = CGSize(width: myCollection.frame.size.width, height: 280)
        return size
    }

Comment: That is in portrait mode and, at least it should have to function no mater if it is scale to fill or aspect fill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka. Finally I did solve this problem. With sizeForItem at, the app could function without problems. I was lost or mislead looking for a way to change the image content mode, but this is not the right way. The correct way is resize once you rotate: for this you need the func  willTransition toNewCollection: UITraitCollection. Inside you create a variable layout that is of type UICollectionViewFlowLayout. With the help of a conditional, is possible to define how you want the with and heigt after rotation.This post is clear and concise for those curious: [UICollectionView Cell Resizing on Device Rotation](https://codeburst.io/uicollectionview-cell-resizing-on-device-rotation-45df462fc178). 
Here the implementation I did in my project: `

```
override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape,
        let layout = myCollection.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
        let with = myCollection.frame.size.width
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: with, height: 280)
        layout.invalidateLayout()
    }

    else if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape,
        let layout = myCollection.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
        let with = myCollection.frame.size.width
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: with/2, height: 280)
```